# How do I run 2 versions of a Docker Compose Config?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am developing a feature on a project that deploys a SQL Container and the Service Container.
Since the build takes time and I need to compare against the older implementation, it would be ideal to compose 2 different deployments and then resume them when required. I am still exploring Docker and might have missed something. The following is the yml file.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  mssql:
    image: <MSSQL_IMAGE>
    ports: <AVAILABLE_PORTS>
    expose: <EXPOSED_PORTS>
    networks:
      ed_network:
        aliases:
          - mssql.local.com

  ed_server:
    image: "ed_local:latest"
    build:
      dockerfile: <PATH_TO_DOCKERFILE>
    ports: <AVAILABLE_PORTS>
    expose: <EXPOSED_PORTS>
    hostname: local.com
    privileged : true
    networks:
      ed_network:
        aliases:
          - ed.local.com
    depends_on: 
      - mssql

networks:
  ed_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mssql_data:
```

Comment: If you're just looking to e.g., change a tag, you can use [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution).

Comment: Variable substitution might work. But How do I manage it as separate docker-composes so that the containers don't get overwritten

Comment: You can use the [COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) environment variable or command-line option to distinguish the services. This variable can be added to your `.env` files along with your other variables.

Comment: Let me check and confirm if this works for my use case.

Comment: @hmm looks like that worked for my use case. -p was the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go my parameterize your docker compose files using environment variables (containing for example the port definitions) and then start it two times. With a little shell 'magic' those environment variables can be calculated. [this is called variable substitution]

You can also opt for multiple docker-compse files overriding values. You can add them in order using the `-f` flag. Using `-p` you can then provide a project name to distinguish between running configurations/versions. Designing the overrides has to be done with enough care to have that system running.

Both options have their drawbacks and neither of them is nice. But they do work in principal.

I looked a bit in my bookmarks and found the article I've read to get those ideas here: https://runnable.com/docker/advanced-docker-compose-configuration

Comment: Does this mean that I can duplicate the docker compose files and then have v1 and v2. So that when I deploy the containers don't get overwritten?

Comment: Probably you may want to add `-p`

Comment: -p helped definitely. Looks like you need to build overrides properly whenever you need to do switch between multiple env.

Comment: If that helps you and is a possible answer please mark it like this for others to find